# Android - Google Play like tabs

Tags: android, tabs, google-play

Google has just implemented a [new look](http://oi43.tinypic.com/2wqs4t1.jpg) to their tabs in Google Play.

I know this can be done with ViewPagerIndicator, yet I wouldn't like to use another library in my application and bump the app's size by another MB or so.

I am currently using the android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip (like in the old Google Play), and I'm wondering if the new look can also be implemented using the android support library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been looking for something that wouldn't bump my app's size and it seems like this is the one. Thank you :-)

Comment: do we have to use external library, by default Android did not have this new sliding tab?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### Design Support Library (current method).

The Design Support Library includes the `TabLayout` widget which allows you to implement a Google Play-lie tabs:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and then initializing it:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

For a full example see the [Cheesesquare app](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)

### PagerSlidingTabStrip Library

This is a ready-to-use library that you can [find on Github](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip).

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]

Comment: can i able to customize the tab bar(bring it to down of the screen) in this library. if so how?

Answer (score 34):

Google finally released their sliding tabs api.

To use SlidingTabsBasic, you first need to download the zip file from:
http://developer.android.com/downloads/samples/SlidingTabsBasic.zip

1. Include the 2 java source files in the com.example.android.common.view package into your project. You may choose to move them to a suitable package in your project.
2. To use the component, simply add it to your view hierarchy. Then in your Activity or Fragment, provide the SlidingTabsBasic your viewPager by calling 
   **mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);**

Example layout from Google:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout
          android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/viewpager"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0px"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Example code in the onCreate() method of your Activity:

```
mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
```

For more details, follow the example in the zip file
SlidingTabsBasicFragment.java and fragment_sample.xml

Comment: Please include the essential parts of the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

try this [library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

[Sample project](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)

It uses `ViewPager` with fragment to display tabs as on google play.

Comment: if you have implemented this project then can i ask 1 question?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the ViewPagerIndicator size is too big and I would like to my app as small as possible, that's why I have chosen not to use the ViewPagerIndicator.

Comment: @EladCohen: When you tried ViewPagerIndicator, and you ran a production build to see what the net size increase was after ProGuard got rid of unused classes, what did you learn?

Comment: I actually didn't run a production build yet, I am still developing my app (which I about to finish soon hopefully) and only then I will start testing it out on real devices insted of emulators. Is it possible to compile my application with ProGuard and use it on an emulator?

Comment: The Eclipse plugin does not make it easy to run a "proguarded" application directly. That said, nothing prevents you to generate an APK and push it to the emulator using adb. Also, as a word of advice, don't wait until the end to test on real devices. You could get some nasty surprises

Comment: Thank you very much nicopico & CommonsWare for the tips, I will test it out.