# how to display Action bar above TabNavigation bar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, tabview

here is my code to create action bar

```
// enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color.white));
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    for (int i=1; i <= 3; i++) {
        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
        tab.setText("Tab " + i);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

    }
```

here is output of my code
[image]

But I wont display like this
[image]

Please anyone help me for this 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Quoting docs

> The tabs provided by the ActionBar are ideal because they adapt to
>   different screen sizes. For example, when the screen is wide enough
>   the tabs appear in the action bar alongside the action buttons (such
>   as when on a tablet, shown in figure 7), while when on a narrow screen
>   they appear in a separate bar (known as the "stacked action bar",
>   shown in figure 8). In some cases, the Android system will instead
>   show your tab items as a drop-down list to ensure the best fit in the
>   action bar.

Figure 7  and 8 can be viewed @ http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

If you are looking for slidingtab's

https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html

Similar to

[Android - Google Play like tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544162/android-google-play-like-tabs)

Comment: thanks.. I run app on diff device it work.. but according to device tab is moving?