# android 5.0 material design tabs

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-5.0-lollipop

What is the best and easy way to implement material design style tabs just like in the latest Google NewsStand app? That is exactly what I'm looking for but don't know where to start. Any help/direction provided is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Now you can just use `TabLayout` in Android Support Design Library.

Comment: Lollipop tabs are very simple to implement & straight forward.  You need to use support library for backward compatibility.  refer this http://www.feelzdroid.com/2015/07/create-lollipop-tabs-in-android-example.html. This will give one simple idea on how to implement basic lollipop tabs.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This [post](https://plus.google.com/+ChrisBanes/posts/ZqVBYudxvFv) of @ChrisBanes (Developer Programs Engineer for Android) explain the situation with the new Toolbar.

So [this](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/project.html) sample can help.

As well as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRg_eDfQ8fk) DevBytes video.

If you want a library, you can go for [this one](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) but It is not updated to material design (I forked it, and If I have some time, I will try to update it).

You can find more information about the new API 21 in [@ChrisBanes blog](https://chris.banes.me/) as well as [the official android blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/whats-new-in-android-50-lollipop.html)

**EDIT:** You can find material design tabs in this repo [jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip) :

I basically did 4 changes to the original library, so far (I will add Toolbar and fix some stuff tomorrow):

1. Change the default parameters of the tabs layout to make it look like more material.
2. The indicator is center by default while swiping tabs.
3. The alpha value of the titles change depending the selected position.
4. Ability to pass customTabs implementing the interface ´CustomTabProvider` in your adapter.

   - In case the customTab have a view with id `@+id/tab_title`, it will be use to place the title and alpha will act as usual.
   - If this interface is not implemented then, the default Tab layout will be use (TextView).

If you want you can use a custom tab with ripples using any of this libraries:

- https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect
- https://github.com/siriscac/RippleView
- https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple
- https://github.com/03uk/RippleDrawable

**EDIT2:** I changed the ActionBar for the new support library Tooolbar. I have also applied colors dynamically to the tabs,toolbar and statusBar. You can see the example working in android 4.4.3 on the following gif.

I sent a PR with my changes. If the original project owner doesn't update the maven library, and push it to maven I will push my library fork to maven central.

[image: material_tabs]

Comment: Thanks @jpardogo for this beautiful library. 

compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.+' is the way to go. :)

Answer (score 7):

I personally love [jpardogo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1787135/jpardogo)'s library [jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip).

One thing that I found missing in it though is ripple effect as seen in:
[image: Material tabs with ripple effect]

So I decided to make my own library, based on PagerSlidingTabStrip, and with customizable ripple effect: [pizza/MaterialTabs](https://github.com/pizza/MaterialTabs).

You can also find a sample on the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.karim.materialtabs.sample), customize your tabs there, then generate your code and export it instantly! :)

Answer (score 3):

I am using the DrawerLayout, had switched to the latest appcompat, compiled with api 21 and got this material theme. Make sure you use drawer from v7.
Description:
http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/

Comment: appcompat already supports material design??

Comment: Yes the latest version supports this