# How to Make Tabs Like Material Play Store

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-5.0-lollipop, android-navigation

I was wondering how I would go about making something identical to the tabs that the Google play store has. Ideally I want to do this with an ActionBar and not a toolbar.

Also note, these are not the same tabs that were used in Holo. I want to get the look of the bottom one:

http://apktribe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/google-play-51-640x454.png

One more thing: I have a navigation drawer, and I want it to go OVER the tabs but not the actionbar (again, refer to the material play store). Also, I know its been said not to do this - but google does it themselves and I like the look :).

Thanks!

Comment: use latest appcompact .

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442941/android-5-0-material-styled-tabs

Comment: @piyush Which API in the appcompat library?