# Change color of tab indicator

Tags: android, android-layout

I came upon this solution to changing the color of the tab indicator, however, it's over 2 years old and (possibly) outdated:

[TabWidget current tab bottom line color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Is there are *elegant* way to changing the color of the tab indicator, i.e. the underline that's shown at the bottom of an active tab:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEt5s.png

Thanks.

Comment: The new way is to use TabLayout. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

Comment: And usually you mix this with a AppBarLayout, Toolbar and a CoordinatorLayout as shown in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680824/how-to-use-a-tablayout-with-toolbar-inside-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Answer (score 0):

**See:**
[Android 5.0 Material-styled tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442941/android-5-0-material-styled-tabs)

Or look through the [documentation for the Design Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#design), referenced as such:

```
compile "com.android.support:design:22.2.0"
```