# Viewpager Page Transformer for 2 multiple images

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

i want viewpager animation where i have 4 images, while swiping from right to left, 1st image must hold its position and new image will come over it.
See the Housing Application(Home Screen Animation) on play store for more details. I want the exactly same behaviour for my app. Please place solution for it. Thank you.

Comment: you can use a framelayout and put an image over the viewpager at the same location.
the turn the visibility off when you are moving to a position you don't want to show that image on.

Comment: see this stackoverflow conversion [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544162/android-google-play-like-tabs)